# String concatenation with python and xpath

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, string-formatting, string-concatenation

Instead of writing 10+ IF statements, I'm trying to create one IF statement using a variable. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with how to implement string concatenation for xpath using python. Can anyone teach me how to perform string formatting for the following code segments?

I would greatly appreciate it, thanks.

```
   if page_number == 1:
        next_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Go to page 2"]')
        next_link.click()

        page_number = page_number + 1
        time.sleep(30)

   elif page_number == 2:
        next_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Go to page 3"]')
        next_link.click()

        page_number = page_number + 1
        time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: XPath has nothing to do with your problem—you just need to know how to concatenation two strings to get a new string; the fact that you’re using the result as an XPath path is irrelevant—and it makes it hard for you to search for docs or existing questions, and scares away people who could answer your question but think they can’t because they don’t know XPath.

Comment: Anyway, you can concatenate two strings just by adding them (but you have to convert the number `page_number` into a string first), or you can just use string formatting instead of concatenation to make things a little simpler. But are things you should be able to find answers for readily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for-loop`

Ex:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    next_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Go to page {0}"]'.format(str(i+1)))     #using str.format for page number
    next_link.click()
    time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not about string concatenation, but about simple problem solution...

Instead of clicking particular link on pagination you can click "Next" button:

```
pages_number = 10

for _ in range(pages_number):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Go to next page']").click()
    time.sleep(30)
```

If you need to open specific page you can use below:

```
required_page = 3

driver.find_element_by_link_text(required_page).click()
```

P.S. I assumed you are talking about [this site](https://bodyspace.bodybuilding.com/member-search)